# How to fetch values from a JSON file on click event using ID and display the values in a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I'm trying to view and edit data on two separate DIV tags.
I have implemented the click even to show the edit form on click event of the edit button in the view page.
Now what i want is, if i click the edit button, i want to fetch the particular items Values and populate it in a form.
i.e, checkbox values should be checked, input fields filled and radiobutton selected.
Here is how i got so far,

HTML:

```
<div class="panelList" id="panelList" hidden>
<form action="#" name="">
    <label class="uno">Panel Category:</label> 
    <span class="spec1">
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="panel2[]">&nbspRegular&nbsp&nbsp
    <input type="checkbox" value="2" name="panel2[]">&nbspReduced fee</input>&nbsp&nbsp
    <input type="checkbox" value="3" name="panel2[]">&nbspLimited Assistance Referral</input>&nbsp&nbsp
    <input type="checkbox" value="4" name="panel2[]">&nbspCourt Programs</input>
    </span>
    </br>
    <label class="uno">Group Panel:</label>
    <span class="spec2">
        <input type='text' list='listid2' id='gpanel2'>
        <datalist id='listid2' ></datalist>
    </span></br>
    <label class="uno">Panel Title :</label>
    <span class="spec3">
        <input type="text" name=""></br>
    </span>
    <label class="uno">Free Panel :</label>
    <span class="spec4">
      <input type="radio" name="free2" value="yes" checked>Yes
      <input type="radio" name="free2" value="no">No
    </span> 
    </br>
    <div id="fees2">
        <label class="uno">Fees $ :</label>
        <span class="spec5">
        <input type="text" id="fees3" name="fees3" disabled="disabled" >
        </span>
    </div>
    </br></br></br>
    <div class="col-md-offset-3">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Update" ></input>&nbsp&nbsp
    <input type="reset" class="btn btn-danger" id="cancel2" value="Cancel" onclick="cancelFunction();">
    </div>
</form>
</div>
<div class="addMember" id="addMember" ng-show="panel.isSelected(2)">
</div>
```

JS:

```
 function editFunction(value)
  {
    $("#panelList").show();
    $("#addMember").hide();
    $.getJSON("active.json"),function(result)
    {
        //console.log("hi");
        var categoryArray = result;

        for (var i = 0; i < categoryArray.length; i++) 
        {
            if (categoryArray[i].id == value) 
            {
                return(categoryArray[i]);

            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

$.getJSON("active.json", function(result) 
{
    var panel_arr = ["", "Regular", "Reduced Fee", "Limited Assurance","Court Programs"];
    var ul_block = $("<ul/>");
    $.each(result, function(i, data) 
    {
        var panels = data.panel.split(",");
        var uli_block = $("<ul/>");
            $.each(panels, function(j, jdata)
            {
                var ulii_block = $("<ul/>");
                $(ulii_block).append($("<li/>").html(data.ptitle+'&nbsp&nbsp<a href="#epanel" id='+data.id+' class="btn btn-default active" role="button" onclick="editFunction(id);">Edit</a>'+'&nbsp&nbsp<a href="#" class="btn btn-default active" role="button">Delete</a>'));

                $(uli_block).append($("<li/>").html('<span class="Collapsable">'+panel_arr[panels[j]]+'</span>')).append(ulii_block);
            });
        $(ul_block).append($("<li/>").html('<span class="Collapsable">'+data.gpanel+'</span>').append(uli_block));
    });
    $("#addMember").append(ul_block);
    $(".Collapsable").click(function () {
      $(this).parent().children().toggle();
      $(this).toggle();
    });
    $(".Collapsable").each(function(){
      $(this).parent().children().toggle();
      $(this).toggle();
    });


});
```

JSON:

```
[  
{  
  "id":"1",
  "gpanel":"sfd",
  "ptitle":"sdffd",
  "panel":"1,4",
  "free":"yes",
  "fees":"0.00"
 },
 {  
  "id":"2",
  "gpanel":"sdfd",
  "ptitle":"sdfds",
  "panel":"4",
  "free":"yes",
  "fees":"0.00"
 },
 {  
  "id":"3",
  "gpanel":"sdf",
  "ptitle":"sdf",
  "panel":"4",
  "free":"yes",
  "fees":"0.00"
 },
 {  
  "id":"4",
  "gpanel":"sfd",
  "ptitle":"fes",
  "panel":"1",
  "free":"yes",
  "fees":"0.00"
 },
 {  
  "id":"5",
  "gpanel":"bbbfff",
  "ptitle":"hgffg",
  "panel":"1,2",
  "free":"yes",
  "fees":"0.00"
 }
 ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make this work, you should not pass *id* to *editFunction*, since that variable will be out of scope at the moment the button is clicked.

Also, it seems overkill to request the data from the server again when the user clicks the edit button. Instead you could pass the corresponding object to *editFunction*.

NB: If later you have functionality that mutates that object, you will maintain state, and when the user edits that data again, the previous changes will still be there.

In order to pass an object, it will be more practical to rewrite some of your code that generates the HTML content: instead of relying on the `html` method, use jQuery methods to create these elements. Then you can easily attach a click handler to the edit button that can access a data object.

Here is a snippet that shows the changes. Of course, I do not have your CSS, so this looks ugly, but it works:

```js
function editFunction(data) { // Pass all related data as argument
    $("#panelList").show();
    $("#addMember").hide();
    // Set form elements
    $('.spec1 input').prop('checked', false); 
    data.panel.split(",").forEach(function (jdata) {
        $('.spec1 input[value=' + jdata + ']').prop('checked', true); 
    });
    $('.spec2 input').val(data.gpanel);
    $('.spec3 input').val(data.ptitle);
    $('.spec4 input[value=' + data.free + ']').prop('checked', true);
    $('.spec5 input').val(data.fees);
    return false;
}

function processResult (result) {
    var panel_arr = ["", "Regular", "Reduced Fee", "Limited Assurance",
                     "Court Programs"];
    var ul_block = $("<ul/>");
    $.each(result, function(i, data) 
    {
        var panels = data.panel.split(",");
        var uli_block = $("<ul/>");
        $.each(panels, function(j, jdata)
        {
            var ulii_block = $("<ul/>");
            // Use jQuery methods for generating the content
            $edit = $('<a/>').attr('href', 'javascript:;')
                             .addClass('btn btn-default active')
                             .attr('role', 'button').text('Edit')
                             .css('margin-left', 5);
            $del = $('<a/>').addClass('btn btn-default active')
                             .attr('role', 'button').text('Delete')
                             .css('margin-left', 5);
            $(ulii_block).append(
                $("<li/>").text(data.ptitle).append($edit, $del));
            $(uli_block).append($("<li/>").append(
                    $('<span>').addClass("Collapsable").text(panel_arr[panels[j]])
            )).append(ulii_block);
            // ...so you can attach a click handler that passes an object as argument
            $edit.click(editFunction.bind(null, data));
        });
        $(ul_block).append($("<li/>").append(
             $('<span>').addClass("Collapsable").text(data.gpanel)
        ).append(uli_block));
    });
    $("#addMember").append(ul_block);
    $(".Collapsable").click(function () {
      $(this).parent().children().toggle();
      $(this).toggle();
    });
    $(".Collapsable").each(function(){
      $(this).parent().children().toggle();
      $(this).toggle();
    });
}

// This snippet does not do a request, so uncomment this:
//$.getJSON("active.json", processResult);

// Dummy data (exclude this when doing the real request)
processResult([  
{  
  "id":"1",
  "gpanel":"sfd",
  "ptitle":"sdffd",
  "panel":"1,4",
  "free":"yes",
  "fees":"0.00"
 },
 {  
  "id":"2",
  "gpanel":"sdfd",
  "ptitle":"sdfds",
  "panel":"4",
  "free":"yes",
  "fees":"0.00"
 },
 {  
  "id":"3",
  "gpanel":"sdf",
  "ptitle":"sdf",
  "panel":"4",
  "free":"yes",
  "fees":"0.00"
 },
 {  
  "id":"4",
  "gpanel":"sfd",
  "ptitle":"fes",
  "panel":"1",
  "free":"yes",
  "fees":"0.00"
 },
 {  
  "id":"5",
  "gpanel":"bbbfff",
  "ptitle":"hgffg",
  "panel":"1,2",
  "free":"no",
  "fees":"1.00"
 }
 ]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panelList" id="panelList" hidden>
<form action="#" name="">
    <label class="uno">Panel Category:</label> 
    <span class="spec1">
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="panel2[]">&nbspRegular&nbsp&nbsp
    <input type="checkbox" value="2" name="panel2[]">&nbspReduced fee</input>&nbsp&nbsp
    <input type="checkbox" value="3" name="panel2[]">&nbspLimited Assistance Referral</input>&nbsp&nbsp
    <input type="checkbox" value="4" name="panel2[]">&nbspCourt Programs</input>
    </span>
    </br>
    <label class="uno">Group Panel:</label>
    <span class="spec2">
        <input type='text' list='listid2' id='gpanel2'>
        <datalist id='listid2' ></datalist>
    </span></br>
    <label class="uno">Panel Title :</label>
    <span class="spec3">
        <input type="text" name=""></br>
    </span>
    <label class="uno">Free Panel :</label>
    <span class="spec4">
      <input type="radio" name="free2" value="yes" checked>Yes
      <input type="radio" name="free2" value="no">No
    </span> 
    </br>
    <div id="fees2">
        <label class="uno">Fees $ :</label>
        <span class="spec5">
        <input type="text" id="fees3" name="fees3" disabled="disabled" >
        </span>
    </div>
    </br></br></br>
    <div class="col-md-offset-3">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Update" ></input>&nbsp&nbsp
    <input type="reset" class="btn btn-danger" id="cancel2" value="Cancel" onclick="cancelFunction();">
    </div>
</form>
</div>
<div class="addMember" id="addMember" ng-show="panel.isSelected(2)">
</div>
```

It is now up to you to write the code for updating the information back into the object when the user clicks the Update button.

Comment: It works, thanks a ton. your coding skills are great. I'm just a beginner here sir, so thanks for teaching me how to do it the right way